# SSIS: Error on Execute SQL Task after VS 2019 and SSIS Extention Updates

Tags: sql, ssis

I am getting COM errors when executing or parsing and Execute SQL task in SSIS. This started after updating VS 2019 and the SQL Server Integration Services extension a few days ago. This happens with any query from a simple TRUNCATE to a pretty involved MERGE.

If I parse any query I get the following:

```
TITLE: SQL Task
------------------------------
Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {D149AE87-9D64-42CE-95A7-138CD72D5346} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
------------------------------
```

If I Execute the query I get the following:

```
[Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query ";
MERGE dbo.MCSectionData_RawUpdate msdu
USING dbo..." failed with the following error: "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.". Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.
```

So after hours of googling yesterday, I have yet to find any solution. I tried uninstalling/reinstalling/repairing the VS install, the extension, and SSMS. This morning I started with a clean machine. I am at an absolute loss. If i could figure out which component its talking about, I would attempt to register it. Any ideas would be appreciated.